# Objects unavailable to some nodes in multiple cluster parallel processing

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing

I am trying to optimize a function using the `genoud` genetic optimizer in `R`, which is part of `library(rgenoud)`. I have limitted experience with setting up parallel processing in `R`.

`genoud` has a built in `cluster` option to `makeClusters` whose names are known. I want to set up parallel processing on a single multi-core machine. I understand the local machine's name is `localhost` and repeating the name will use more than one core on the machine.

This approach seems to be working fine for simple functions such as:

```
genout <- genoud(sin, 1, cluster=c('localhost','localhost','localhost'))
```

However when I optimize more complex function structures some of the machines or environments do not find all functions. Here is an example:

```
fun1 <- function(x) {sin(x)}
fun2 <- function(x) {
  x  <- fun1(x)
  ret <- x + cos(x)
  return(ret)
  }
genout <- genoud(fun2, 1, cluster=c('localhost','localhost','localhost'))
```

This gives error

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "fun1"
```

One solution seems to be to embed `fun1` into `fun2`. However, this seems inefficient if `fun2` is run a large number of times (in other cases than the silly example). Is it true that the only way to solve this problem is embedding `fun1` in `fun2`?

**Edit**: Even when embedding, there are more problems when objects need to be passed to `fun2` via `genoud`, see:

```
y=1
fun2 <- function(x,z) {
  fun1 <- function(x) {sin(x)}
  x  <- fun1(x)
  ret <- x + cos(x)*z
  return(ret)
}
genout <- genoud(fun2, 1, cluster=c('localhost','localhost','localhost'), z=y)

>Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
   3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'y' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `genoud` function is not properly evaluating and sending the additional arguments to the workers. In this case, the argument `z` is sent to the workers without being evaluated, so the workers have to evaluate it, but they fail because the variable `y` wasn't sent to the workers.

A work-around is to export the necessary variables to the workers using `clusterExport`, which requires you to explicitly create the cluster object for `genoud` to use:

```
library(rgenoud)
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
fun1 <- function(x) {sin(x)}
fun2 <- function(x, z) {
  x  <- fun1(x)
  x + cos(x) * z
}
y <- 1
clusterExport(cl, c('fun1', 'y'))
genout <- genoud(fun2, 1, cluster=cl, z=y)
```

This also exports `fun1`, which is necessary since `genoud` doesn't know that `fun2` depends on it.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this answer is exhaustive.